# Looking for better errorformat when compile with ant on mac vim

Tags: vim, ant

Currently the `efm` i used on mac is `set efm=%A\ %#[javac]\ %f:%l:\ %m,%A\ %#[aapt]\ %f:%l:\ %m,%-Z\ %#[javac]\ %p^,%-C%.%#`. It can actually locate the error location and show a brief error info, but the detail i can only get by switching to terminal.

BTW, the efm works quite good on archlinux.

Here is the output:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/ccheng/workspace_tb/Android_RollingBall/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/ccheng/workspace_tb/Android_RollingBall/src/hongbosb/rollingball/GLDrawable.java:22: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : void
    [javac] required: int
    [javac]         mEnvProgram = Utils.loadProgram(context, "environment_vertex_shader.glsl", "environment_fragment_shader.glsl");
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /Users/ccheng/workspace_tb/Android_RollingBall/src/hongbosb/rollingball/EnvironmentGLDrawable.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor GLDrawable()
    [javac] location: class hongbosb.rollingball.GLDrawable
    [javac]     public EnvironmentGLDrawable(Context context) {
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac] /Users/ccheng/workspace_tb/Android_RollingBall/src/hongbosb/rollingball/MyRenderer.java:31: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable context
    [javac] location: class hongbosb.rollingball.MyRenderer
    [javac]         mEnvironment = new EnvironmentGLDrawable(context);
    [javac]                                                  ^
    [javac] 3 errors
```

And the following is what my vim missed.

```
[javac] found   : void
        [javac] required: int
        [javac]         mEnvProgram = Utils.loadProgram(context, "environment_vertex_shader.glsl", "environment_fragment_shader.glsl");
        [javac]                                        ^
        [javac]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm going to reformat it so that it's easier (for me) to deal with...

```
let fmt = '%A\ %#[javac]\ %f:%l:\ %m,'
      \ . '%A\ %#[aapt]\ %f:%l:\ %m,'
      \ . '%-Z\ %#[javac]\ %p^,'
      \ . '%-C%.%#'
execute 'set errorformat=' . fmt
```

You only have one line in the javac detector that grabs a message.  You just need to add more of them.  Add the following somewhere above the `%-C` line:

```
      \ . '%C\ %#[javac]\ %m,'
```

You probably also want to do something similar for the aapt messages although if those are one-liners then I think you just strike the `%A` part that begins its line; `%A` means that it's the start of a multiline message so it'll consider everything that follows it part of the aapt message until a `%Z` is matched.  The `%-C` bit says "matches for this are uninteresting"; these are things in your multiline message (e.g. the things that aren't showing up) that you've told vim to skip.

Comment: Great! How can i mark this as right answer after a year! Thank you.